# Use of serveroutput on or DBMS_OUTPUT in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

What is the difference between the use of the script header Set serveroutput on, Set serveroutput on size 1000000 and enable DBMS_OUTPUT in SQLDeveloper, to see clearly the output (success or errors) of procedures PL/SQL or queries made in Oracle Databases. Or have I to use both?

Comment: No difference, same stuff, but one we setup your session for you and write to the dbms_output panel and the other you do everything and see it in the script output panel

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_OUTPUT only writes to a buffer.  It is the responsibility of the client to process that buffer - or not.  The command 'set serverout on' is a *sqlplus directive*, telling *sqlplus* that it is to display the contents of that buffer, *when control is returned to sqlplus*.

I'm not sure exactly what *you* mean when you say " enable DBMS_OUTPUT in SQLDeveloper".  In the SQLDev menu, under 'view' there is an item for 'dbms output', which pops open an additional pane for dbms output. In that pane there is a green 'plus sign' icon that is the SQL Dev equivalent of the sqlplus directive 'set serverout on'. Or you can include the 'set serverout on' directive in your sqlscript, and the output will appear in the 'script output' pane, as SQL Dev accepts most sqlplus directives.